# How to use Hashmaps for key bindings?

Tags: java

I am making a basic little game in Java and I want to have it so that I can use Hashmaps for binding keys..

e.g.- it would be like HashMap
and then I would do:
    hashmap.add(Keys.up, VK_UP);

but this is where I get to my problem, How do i access the hashmap and choose which keys are pressed when the KeyListener returns a pressed key?

Sorry if this question seems baffling but I'm really confused too..

Comment: Do you want to return the value corresponding to the key from the HashMap? could you give a sample input/output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You insert key and value to the hashmap using [`map.put(key,value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) and retrieves a value based on a key using [`map.get(key)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)

You need to make sure that the class of the keys overrides both [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) and [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) [For library classes - it already is]

Answer (score 1):

Since all key types for KeyEvent are of type int use the following hash map :

```
HashMap<Integer, Boolean> keysState = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

.
.
.

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  keysState.put(e.getKeyCode(), true);
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
  keysState.put(e.getKeyCode(), false);
}
```

and now you can test if a key is pressed by :

```
if (keysState.get(KeyEvent.VK_UP)) {
   // Up key is pressed so do the desired action
}
```

Comment: This will throw a runtime exception if the key hasn't been pressed at all since the value returned from the get method will be a null value. For this to work the HashMap needs to be initialised with all the possible keys pointing to a "false" value.

Comment: @Alonso is right. Make sure the map is initialized with the proper key codes (value = false for all)